# I can't find HTML tag in Collective\Html laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

In my old application of Laravel 4.2 I used a lot following syntax in my blade templates

```
{{HTML::link('admin/categories','Manage Categories')}}
{{HTML::style('css/normalize')}}
```

Now I am converting it to Laravel 5.3 and I read illuminate package is deprecated, I installed aravelcollective/html package and following is working perfectly.

```
   {{Form::open(array('url'=>'store/search', 'method'=>'get'))}}
```

But I can't figure out how to above tags I tried following format but still getting error of HTML not found

```
{{HTML::link('admin/categories','Manage Categories')}}
{{HTML::style('css/normalize')}}
```

and

```
{!! HTML::link('admin/categories','Manage Categories')!!}
{!! HTML::style('css/normalize')!!}
```

But nothing working, all giving me error, as I read documentation really there is no more any reference to HTML tag, so do I have to use normal html or is there any other way to do it properly as this HTML tag was very fast way of doing templating

Comment: Its `{{Html::link('admin/categories','Manage Categories')}}`
not `{{HTML::link('admin/categories','Manage Categories')}}`
I mean change `HTML` to `Html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add aliases in config/app.php?

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

After this try to run *composer clear-cache* command in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo link_to('admin/categories', $title = 'Manage Categories', $attributes = array(), $secure = null);
```